# Does Mapbox GL JS have a "hit tolerance" attribute for rendered features?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

By "hit tolerance", I mean that a feature can be selected/interacted by the user with when the mouse pointer is within a certain pixel tolerance of the feature's rendered position. [OpenLayers has a good demonstration of this concept here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/hit-tolerance.html).

I couldn't find anything in the Mapbox GL JS documentation that would match this functionality. Are there any good workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware - or at least, nothing the user can configure.

The usual workaround is like this:

1. Create another layer with a very low non-zero opacity, which is physically larger than the visible object. For instance, a line with a greater `line-width` or a circle with a greater `circle-radius`.
2. Put this layer beneath the visible layer.
3. Check for hits on both the visible and almost-invisible layer.

You can see an example of this being implemented [here](https://github.com/stevage/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/816c7ab9d755cceea771f099b028374907117126/src/modes/draw_line_string.js#L215).

Comment: If you happen to be using `react-map-gl`, there is a [clickRadius](http://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/interactive-map#clickradius) property, but it looks very specific to that lib and I couldn't find an equivalent in `mapbox-gl-js`.

Answer (score 0):

"Features" can be many things in mapbox.

If your context is MapBox *Markers*, it is fairly easy to increase the css padding property on the markers [element](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker#getelement). This will achieve the effect you seek.  e.g.

```
marker.getElement().style.padding = '10px';
```

well at least that's how I solved it ;)